# GXT column sort, move blue triangle

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a business requirement to move the little blue thingie like this:
(I guess this behavior is somewhere inside GXT which should be overridden, if possible..)

[image]

So it should be INSIDE the text field, before the text. I searched google, without success. I have no idea where to start :)
Thanks in advance!

Update: I'm adding the solution as an answer

Anybody has an idea on how to apply this custom CSS to the colum elements? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the solution is as here:

```
ColumnConfig<?, String> column;

column.setColumnHeaderClassName("gridcolumnheader");
```

CSS:

```
.gridcolumnheader img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 5px;
}

.gridcolumnheader input{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

This basically targets the column header, and targets seperately the img and the input tag.